# What is this strange looking tree with hairy-type growths near the leaves?

Tags: identification, trees

What species is this tree? What are the hairy balls on it?

*click on the photo for full size*

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site! For identification questions, it's always a good idea to include detail photos of leaves, bark, flowers, fruit... and state where in the world you found it.

Answer (score 8):

It looks a lot like a smoke tree ([Cotinus coggygria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotinus_coggygria)).

While it only rarely forms a tree, sometimes the bush grows into the shape of a small tree.

The "fluffy balls" are seed heads, consisting of elongated remenants of the flowers, surrounding the tiny seeds.

Comment: Yes, smoke bush, badly in need of heavy pruning

Comment: @kevinsky Or the result of a misguided attempt of growing a tree ;-)

Comment: Actually, it does look rather Seuss-like, perhaps like the [Truffula tree from The Lorax](http://seuss.wikia.com/wiki/Truffula_Tree). I might try to grow one like this myself... :)

Comment: Hey Smoke Tree/shrub are very beautiful and very cool.  They need 'guidance'...pruning.  I'd make sure my smoke tree never gets too high by cutting the leader back.  Thin all skinny twigs/branches out of the middle and leave only branches that grow outwards.  Get rid of redundant branches, stuff that crosses, stuff that isn't healthy.  Just do a little pruning every few months.  Fall color is spectacular!!  This is a specimen tree, so planting just one is great.